# about publish() method in NetStream AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server, netstream, rtmpd

Can i use publish method to record flv file with streaming servers other than Flash Media Server, or it is just meant for FMS? How about crtmp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! RED5 or Wowza may record a published stream.

Answer (score 1):

crtmp (or rtmpd) server can definitely be used too, as long as [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665312/error-in-record-playback-audio-app-using-flash-evostream) doesn't bother you.