# Error in Record / Playback audio - App using flash & Evostream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, streaming, rtmpd

I'm using evostream, a commercial version of rtmpd.

While making a sample record & playback app in flash, I'm able to publish **live** streams & play them back but not **record** or **append**.

```
netStream.publish(_streamName, "record");
```

Use of the above in flash leads to close of connection & a series of errors in the server console.

Here is a part of that series which I believe gives some insight.

```
...

    /common/src/utils/misc/file.cpp:78 Unable to open file  with mode `w+b`. Error was: (2) No such file or directory
    /thelib/src/protocols/rtmp/streaming/outfilertmpflvstream.cpp:44 Unable to initialize file 
    /thelib/src/protocols/protocolmanager.cpp:45 Enqueue for delete for protocol CTCP(10) <-> TCP(4) <-> [IR(5)]
    /thelib/src/application/baseclientapplication.cpp:262 Stream INR(2) with name `_20120626133918` unregistered from application `evostreamms` from protocol IR(5)
    /thelib/src/application/baseclientapplication.cpp:262 Stream OFRFLV(3) with name `_20120626133918.flv` unregistered from application `evostreamms` from protocol IR(5)
    /thelib/src/application/baseclientapplication.cpp:240 Protocol CTCP(10) <-> TCP(4) <-> [IR(5)] unregistered from application: evostreamms
    /common/src/utils/misc/file.cpp:476 File not opened
    /thelib/src/protocols/rtmp/streaming/outfilertmpflvstream.cpp:53 Unable to write FLV signature
    /thelib/src/protocols/rtmp/basertmpprotocol.cpp:960 RTMP connection no longer associated with an application
    /thelib/src/netio/epoll/tcpcarrier.cpp:89 Unable to signal data available
    /thelib/src/netio/epoll/iohandlermanager.cpp:129 Handlers count changed: 9->8 IOHT_TCP_CARRIER
...
```

All I can assume from the above is that somehow the file cannot be created beacause of access permissions. But I have set the permissions of all folders & files to full access.

I don't know where to look anymore. Anyone having any idea on how to move forward may kindly share it.

---

**EDIT**

A complete log of errors can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ThruGN05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it myself. Looks like you just discovered a bug. The work around until the next release, is to create a file like this:

[MEDIA_FOLDER]/[_streamName].flv

Is not pretty at all, but it will be definitely address in the next release. 
Another work around would be to use the record CLI command

---

You can send the log files to contact@rtmpd.com or post all of it either here or on pastebin.com. You cut out the most interesting part from it which is just above the first line that you pasted

Comment: Thank you for answering. I had figured your solution for which I wrote a script & executed it to create the file manually. But didn't feel it quite right with the hack, hence the post. I will update the log snippet, here itself.